# Dropdownlist in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I have a dropdownlist displaying "yes" and "no".If i select yes from dropdownlist 1 should be saved to database.And if I select no,0 should be saved.If i select yes from dropdown in Create page,it should display yes in Index page but value saved should be 1

Model is:

```
public class State
{
    [Key]
    public int StateID { get; set; }       
    public string Code { get; set; }        
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Active { get; set; }  
}
```

Create.cshtml

```
 <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Active,new[]{new SelectListItem() {Text="Yes",Value="1"},
                                                            new SelectListItem(){Text="No",Value="0"}})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Active)
```

Index.cshtml:

```
   <td>
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Active)
    </td>
```

I got dropdown with values yes and no and it is storing 1 and 0 correspondingly.But in Index page it is dispaying 1 and 0 instead of yes and no...
Please help...

Comment: Is `Model.Active` properly set?

Comment: i didnt get your question..

Comment: If i select yes from dropdown in Create page,it should display yes in Index page but value saved should be 1

Comment: Sorry, I had misread the question; I thought it wasn't displayed correctly in the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, it's displaying the value of the integer value your are saving (0 or 1). To display 'Yes' or 'No' you will need to convert the value back to a string and pass it to your view model. Ideally you should create a view model for your index page.

```
public class IndexViewModel
{

    public string Active {get;set;}

    ...

}
```

Your controller logic

```
if(Active == 0)
    active = "No"
 else
    active = "Yes"

return(new IndexViewModel 
{
   Active = active 
   ...
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this

@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>item.Active ==0 ? "Yes":"No")